# smarty tags to php convertion/replacement

Tags: php, smarty

**Here is the following "Smarty" tpl code:**

```
{if !$document}
    {assign var=document value=15}
    {"document set"}
{/if}
```

**bellow is the equivalent code but in PHP I've converted manually:**

```
<?php if (!$document) { ?>
    <?php $document=15; ?>
    <?php echo "document set"; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is to find the most simple way to convert/replace such lines of code automatically without the use of "Smarty" internal engine routines.

I thought maybe regex is a solution.

If you could share your thoughts/solutions on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question can be rephrased as "How do I use Smarty without using Smarty?". This seems pointless, either use Smarty or don't, but thinking that you could replace such a large library of functionality as Smarty with a Regex is 'unreasonable' to say the least.

Comment: I've got tonnes of tpls with smarty, I need a solution which allows me to convert most of them into php code. Why? I consider smarty as an additional and unnecessary layer. It's a one shot operation. the most simple solution would be couple of regex expressions, but things get more complicated when it comes to loops.

Comment: Smarty does cache the conversions in the cache folder. You could just run the page once through a separate sandbox smarty site and then go find the cached version of the file in the cache directory. Though this sounds tedious and quite silly.

Comment: "It's a one shot operation." Yes, particularly if you turn caching on and set the cache lifetime to be very long.

Comment: You can always use alternative ( smaller ) template engines like [RainTPL](http://www.raintpl.com/)